# User Interface with Image

Tags: android, user-interface, android-studio

[image]

I am making an app to include a view with the picture as the background. As you can see in the picture, it has cells. I want the users of the app to be able to click each cell individually and a pop up menu will appear.

I have tried putting buttons on top of each cell but I don't know what layout to use in android studio. If anyone has other suggestions on how I can create a user interface with each cell on the image please let me know!

Help me ObiWan.

Comment: Use a TableLayout  : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_table_layout.htm

Comment: @Radix once I use this how would I code the buttons to directly fit into each cell?

Comment: @Radix I tried dragging a button on top of the table layout and it doesn't stay where I put it

Comment: I think it would be difficult to try and match up buttons on an image background. As soon as you start getting into varying screen sizes and densities, I think it's going to be a nightmare trying to match everything up. I think a better option would be to design the buttons and layout the way you want it to be (the interface), THEN design the image to fit nicely behind it so it looks good.

Comment: @NoChinDeluxe So i would place all the buttons on the screen to make it look like the image I posted, then how would I put the image on top? THANKS

Comment: @ADAM9611222 - It really depends on what the actual interface looks like. I can't really tell from the pic you posted, but if you were wanting the user to click on graphics in the background image as buttons, then you could probably make individual `ImageButtons` that look like those graphics, place them in your layout, then produce a background image to go behind them. You'd basically be splitting your original background image into a bunch of smaller images. I'm not sure if that's clear. It's tough to describe without just showing you a visual example haha.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand what you are saying! @NoChinDeluxe